# jquery show/hide

Tags: jquery

Im not so good with JavaScript or jQuery, but I'm trying to get an image to show when I hover over the `<div>` element. The problem is that it is happening with the other ones too.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#event .event").hover(function () {
        $(".event img").show("slow");
    },
    $(".event img").mouseout(function () {
        $(".event img").hide("slow");
    }));

});
```

Html code:

```
<div id="event">
    <div class="event">
         <h4>name1</h4>

        <p>some text1</p>
        <img style='position:relative; display:none;' src='img1' alt='' />
    </div>
    <div class="event">
         <h4>name2</h4>

        <p>some text2</p>
        <img style='position:relative; display:none;' src='img2' alt='' />
    </div>
</div>
```

But the image is coming on both, or all five if I have five.. Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. IMO this solution is easier to understand.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#event .event").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('img').show();
    }, function(){
       $(this).find('img').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the `$` function is often times used to define the context. Meaning, your selector will be used relative to a particular element, or selector.

```
$(".event") // finds all .event elements
$(".event", this) // finds all .event elements within 'this'
```

With this in mind, we can modify your code to look within the `.event` element currently being entered or existed to find the appropriate image:

```
​$("#event .event").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $("img", this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $("img", this).hide();
    }
});​​​
```

This binds some logic to every element that matches the `#event .event` selector. Each one of these will have a handler bound to their `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Anytime you hover one of those elements matched by the selector, we reference that particular element using the `this` keyword.

If you enter the first `#event .event` element on the page, `this` refers to that element. Likewise, if you exit that element, `this` refers to that element being exited. Recalling the first point of this response, that means `$("img", this)` will target every image within the element raising the `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` events to begin with.

Also, double-check your use of `.hover()`; this method takes two parameters, functions, that will be called when you mouseenter and when you mouseleave, respectively:

```
$("#event .event").hover( showImages, hideImages );

function showImages () {
    $("img", this).show();
}

function hideImages () {
    $("img", this).hide();
}
```

Or you could place those directly inside the `.hover` method as anonymous functions:

```
$("#event .event").hover(
    function(){ $("img", this).show(); }, 
    function(){ $("img", this).hide(); }
);
```

Comment: @nodde You need to be more specific; what doesn't work? The above code works, I have tested it against your HTML.

Comment: yes, it working, but it dosent work on my site. It was working when i did not use @this . So i think there is somthing wrong on the site. But i dont know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding and showing all the images, you need to use the `this` keyword to target only the current element, not all of them, here is another simpler solution using toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#event .event").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            $('img', this).toggle(e.type=='mouseenter');
    });
});
```